# How can I display the output of each loop on a "for" loop?

Tags: html, loops, canvas, for-loop

I'm a total noob and I´m working on a "prime numbers" drawing/animation using HTML5 Canvas and JS. I'm having a hard time with the 'for' loop because the browser is displaying the drawing only after the 'for' loop is done and not while this is working (Displaying the output of each loop, like an animation).

**HTML/css:**

```
<!doctype html>


<html>
<head>
</head>
    <style>

    body
        {
        background: #999999
        }

    #canvas 
        {
        background: white;
        border: 19px solid black;
        }

    </style>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="4000" height="4000">

    Bájate un nuevo navegador!!

    </canvas>
    <script src="jscode.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

**JS (jscode.js):**

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext ('2d');

// Text properties 
context.font = '32pt Arial';
context.fillStyle = 'DeepSkyBlue';
context.StrokeStyle = 'DarkSlateGray';

// Line properties
context.StrokeStyle = "rgb (200,0,0)";
context.lineWidth = 1;

// Each Natural number is represented by a segment
// "t" corresponds to the length of each segment.
var t = 3;

// Starting position within the canvas.
var x = 500;
var y = 500;


//Array stores every movement's direction.
//(We need to know the last segment direction in order "continue" the drawing) 
var Dmemory = new Array();

// Drawing using a Path function.  
// Drawing "manually".
        context.beginPath();
        //0 
        context.moveTo(x,y);
        Dmemory [0] = "A";
        //1
        /*UP*/ var y = y - t;
        context.lineTo(x,y);
        Dmemory [1] = "A";

// Continue using a "for" loop.         
// Variable "num" is the LIMIT. The program will run until the loop gets to this number.            
    var num = 10000;

// The program begins with 1 and starts counting adding 1+.
    for (i=2 ; i < num ; i++ )
    {

//Creating a "Divisors tracking variable".  
//We are going to divide each number between all the natural numbers below to verify if its a prime.
        var contador = 0;
        for ( div = i ; div > 0 ; div--)
        {   

            if (i%div == 0)
            {
            contador = contador + 1; 
            }
            //Breaking condition: More than 2 divisors.
            if (contador>2)
            {
            break;
            }

        }
        //Primes Test: Primes have ONLY two divisors: Themselves and number One
        if (contador == 2) 
            {   
                //If Prime: check the last movements direction and proceed.
                switch (Dmemory[i - 1])
                {

                case "A":
                    var y = y - t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y);
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="D";
                    break;

                case "B":
                    var y = y + t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y);
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="I";
                    break;

                case "D":
                    var x = x + t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y);
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="B";
                    break;

                case "I":
                    var x = x - t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y); 
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="A";

                }


            }
        else
            {
                //If not Prime: check the last movement direction and proceed.
                switch (Dmemory[i - 1])
                {

                case "A":
                    var y = y - t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y);
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="A";
                    break;

                case "B":
                    var y = y + t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y);
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="B";
                    break;

                case "D":
                    var x = x + t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y);
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="D";
                    break;

                case "I":
                    var x = x - t;
                    context.lineTo(x,y); 
                    context.stroke();
                    Dmemory[i]="I";
                    break;

                }

            }


    }
```

I´ve been reading other answers and now I understand the main reason: JavaScript in the web browser is single-threaded.

But, is there any way to accomplish what I need? (What I need: To display the drawing on screen as the loop progresses)

Thank you in advance,

Greetings From Lima - Perú

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to report progress, you have to compute on a given interval, so that the system gets enough moments to 'breathe'.
Below is a fake interval computation that will be called on a regular basis. I hope it can help you to get to your solution.

http://jsbin.com/qarivina/1/edit?js,output

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext ('2d');
setupNow();

function computeFromTo(i1, i2) {
  var st = now();
  for (var i=i1; i<i2; i++) computeForIndex(i);
  var ed = now();
  var timeTaken = (ed-st);
}

function computeForIndex(i) {
  var res = Math.pow(i,2.5)/Math.abs(1 + Math.sin(i));
}

function beginCallCompute() {
  var startIndex    = 0  ;
  var indexIncrease = 500 ;
  var lastIndex     = 500000;

  var computeInterval = setInterval(callCompute, 5);

  function callCompute() {
    computeFromTo(startIndex, startIndex+indexIncrease);
    startIndex += indexIncrease;
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillText(startIndex, 20, 20);
    if (startIndex>=lastIndex) {
       clearInterval(computeInterval);
    }
  }

}

beginCallCompute();


// ---------------------------

function setupNow() {
  window.now = ( performance && performance.now.bind(performance) )|| Date.now ;
}
```